# Converting CSV and reprojecting shapefile to match location of points

Tags: python, raster, coordinate-system, shapefile, csv

I have a .csv file with coordinates which should be converted into .shp file. The CSV file is built by analysing simple .tif raster without metadata.

As far as no CRS is saved in .csv file, the shapefile's location doesn't coincide with the .tif raster location with metadata (with CRS).

Using Python, how can I reproject my shapefile such that points are in the same place where raster is?

Answer (score 4):

You need to define the projection system in the shapefile.

To do it with Python, you can use geopandas library in Python.

To obtain a shapefile (with CRS) from CSV, the following tasks need to be performed:

1. Read the CSV file as a geodataframe in geopandas.
2. Assign desired CRS to the geodataframe.
3. Convert the geodataframe to shapefile.

For further information on how to read CSV file in geopandas and to convert it to shapefile, refer to [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61122875/geopandas-how-to-read-a-csv-and-convert-to-a-geopandas-dataframe-with-polygons) ,  [link2](https://anitagraser.com/2019/01/23/from-csv-to-geodataframe-in-two-lines/)  and [geopandas documentation](https://geopandas.org/docs/user_guide/io.html)